# How can I sanitise this SQL query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, brakeman

I am writing a SQL query in the Post model to search the database to match the query with the body of a post. I am using `Brakeman` gem to help audit the security of the application, and it has returned the SQL query as vulnerable to injection.

The query,

```
def self.search(search)
    where("body LIKE '%#{search}%'")
end
```

`Post` controller,

```
if params[:search]
    @posts = Post.search(params[:search]).order("created_at    DESC").paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
else
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this:

```
def self.search(search)

        where("body LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
end
```

Comment: will try. Since I'm new to Rails, do you mind educating me as to why this is a better decision?

Comment: Using the syntax you wrote can give the attacker to gain access to your entire database.
Since an attacker can get full control of payload (for example params[:search]) they can insert whatever they’d like into your where query. 

So instead of passing a string to the conditions option, you should pass an variable to sanitize tainted strings as I said above.  http://gavinmiller.io/2015/fixing-sql-injection-vulnerabilities/